# How to receive charitable in-app donations

Tags: donations, android-inapp-purchase

I am trying to create an app that will allow my users to donate to charity. Obviously it is possible as Just Giving have an app that allows this. However, I cannot find any information about setting this up. Does anyone know how to make this possible on Android? Many thanks

Comment: Please be more specific about problematics of this app.

Comment: Thank you for the question.  The problem is working out Google's requirements when implementing a donation button. How to have Google treat it as a donation rather than an in-app purchase.